# Can you acces Realm Mobile Platform from server side?

Tags: realm-mobile-platform

I was wondering if we could access the Realm Object Server from a server to populate realms so users get them when they next connect via synch?
Or the idea is that users get their data via our server and then put them in the Realm Object Server?
What are the performance implication of both solutions? In our current situation we already use realm to store the data locally and I am wondering what would be the advantage to move to Realm Mobile Platform if we still need to manage all the synch with our servers anyway...
Thanks !
:)

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse you can. You can just write a server application which interacts with the same realm server like your clients do. You can modify data with the server application like you normally do with every of your other clients.

Comment: I guess you can use [nodejs](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/) api